# Error when sending mails to sendmail on ubuntu 17.04

Tags: ubuntu, sendmail

began to use the services scaleway. My server has a private IP (10.10....) and public IP (163.172....).

After sending the letter in the logs I see **"gethostbyaddr(10.10......) failed: 1"**.

Use sendmail. I just need to send itself to e-mail notifications.

Comment: Can you provide more detail about your exact config/setup?

Comment: @neuromatter I have clean installed operating system. Installed sendmail **apt-get install sendmail**. The message In the log "accepted for delivery" and many "Connection timed out with alt4.gmail-smtp-in.l.google.com."

Comment: @neuromatter I read on the forums that ip to add to the hosts file private ip